# I cannot return a value from my array

Tags: java, arrays

This is assessed work so please don't give a straight answer.

My program is supposed to calculate the users grade: "pass" , "fail" or "pass with compensation". However, it doesn't return the answer. I'm unable to figure out why - can anyone help?

public class MarkCalculator {
    static int[] marks = new int[12];

```
//public static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int weighting;
    int coursework;
    int exammark;

    System.out.println("Please enter course work weighting");
    marks[0]= kb.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter course work mark");
    marks[1]= kb.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter exam mark");
    marks[2]= kb.nextInt();


    MarkCalculator mc = new MarkCalculator();
    mc.computeMarks(marks);

}




public String[] computeMarks(int[] marks) {

    final int[] WEIGHTING = {55,66,55,44,33,44};
    String[] results = new String[WEIGHTING.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < marks.length / 2; i++) {

        int exam = marks[i];
        int cw = marks[i];
        int weight = WEIGHTING[i];
        int formula = ((cw + weight) + (exam * (100 - weight)) / 100);

        if (formula >= 40){
            results[i]="PASS";
        } else if ((formula < 39) && (formula > 35)){
            results[i]="COMPENSATION PASS";
        }else{
            results[i]="FAIL";

        }

    }

    return results;
}
```

}

Comment: Just a side note, when `formula==39` result will be FAIL, I don't think this is what you are expecting

Answer (score 3):

```
final int[] WEIGHTING = {};
String[] results = new String[WEIGHTING.length];
```

Here's a problem.  WEIGHTING has no initial size.

Comment: Yes, you can declare variable as final in method.

Comment: I had numbers initialized  in weighting but took them out just playing around with it to hopefully find a solution

Comment: I had six random numbers, but i shouldn't have to initialize numbers because say if someones weighting was outside the 6 numbers?

Comment: @user2961364, then you would need a an `ArrayList` or a some kind of `List`. Arrays don't auto-increment.

Comment: keep in mind also, you haven't given an values to `marks` in your code above.

Comment: ah thanks. I've now done it so : marks[0]= kb.nextInt(); , for all three [1], [2]

Answer (score 1):

Also: you don't initialize marks with anything. Try this:

```
System.out.println("Please enter course work weighting");
        marks[0]= kb.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter course work mark");
        marks[1]= kb.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter exam mark");
        marks[2]= kb.nextInt();

        MarkCalculator mc = new MarkCalculator();
        mc.computeMarks(marks);
```

Comment: hey by mark[0], mark[1] and mark[2]. Do you mean marks[0],marks[1] and marks[2] because mark isn't defined?

Comment: so i've changed ----  final int[] WEIGHTING = {55,66,55,44,33,44}; ---so WEIGHTING now has some numbers as the weighting of the cw.

Comment: but for the markCalculator bit i don't really understand, it doesn't allow me to put numbers inside it to pass marks.

Comment: but when i input mark amounts and weighting the program still terminates without any calculation which it should complete

Comment: do you print your results somewhere like System.out.println(mc.computeMarks(marks).toString());?

Comment: i have return results;

Answer (score 1):

The problem is WEIGHTING is empty

```
final int[] WEIGHTING = {}; // empty
String[] results = new String[WEIGHTING.length];
for (int i = 0; i < marks.length / 2; i++) {

    int exam = marks[i];
    int cw = marks[i];
    int weight = WEIGHTING[i]; // You cant access elements from an empty array
```

Also

```
    MarkCalculator mc = new MarkCalculator();
    mc.computeMarks(marks);
```

here you are passing marks which is empty.

**EDIT**

Reason why your program wasnt working is because you are not catching the result from computeMarks. You should store it in an array inside main like

```
String[] result = mc.computeMarks(marks);

for(int k=0;k<result.length;k++)
{
    System.out.println(result[k]);
}
```

Comment: I've set weighting as final int[] WEIGHTING = {55,66,55,44,33,44};

Comment: and 
        marks[0]= kb.nextInt();
        marks[1]= kb.nextInt();
        marks[2]= kb.nextInt(); so marks isn't empty anymore? still not receiving answer informing me whether it's pass ect